# Checkbox not being checked

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

Looking at this jsFiddle, my checkbox is never getting the `checked` attribute. This is a VERY simple test, and yet I cannot get the alert to show `true`.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZLpHv/

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checky" />

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#checky").click(function() {
       alert($(this).is("checked")); 
    });
});
```

Why does the alert show `false` in both cases? And why does the `checked` attribute never get set onto the checkbox? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why the downvote? Please explain, whoever downvoted?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's actually :

```
$(this).is(":checked")
```

And binding the change event makes it work even if it's checked with the keyboard:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#checky").on('change', function() {
       alert($(this).is(":checked")); 
    });
});
```

Comment: @insertusernamehere - yeah, funny how that happens sometimes!

Comment: @adeneo was spot on, but fyi, as of jQuery 1.6, the preferred way of checking is to use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop1). Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZLpHv/4/

Comment: +1 for being correct, though I'd argue it should really just be `this.checked` - using `$(this).is(':checked')` is a few function calls and a selector too many for me when you can access the property directly.

Answer (score 5):

It's actually: `alert($(this).is(":checked"));`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AdFEf/

Answer (score 2):

You forget the ":".

```
alert($(this).is(":checked"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
   //checkbox
   $("#terms").click(function(){
       //if this...
       //alert("this")...
       if($("#terms").is(':checked'))
       {              
          alert("im checked");
       }
   });
   //button
   $("#buttonID").click(function(e){
       if(!$("#terms").is(':checked'))
       {
           alert("you did not check the agree to terms..."); 
           e.preventDefault();
       }
   });
 }
```

You can use this it works for me